# How to repel nodes only of a certain kind using force graph

Tags: d3.js, nodes, force-layout

My force directed graph has 2 classes of nodes: Regular and Beacon.  I want my Beacons to repel Regulars, but not other Beacons.
  I'm using my own function to move Regulars to some radius outside of Beacons, but it's really clunky-- the Regulars are gathering around the 4 corners of Beacons and due to my collision resolution function, the Regulars sometimes overlap the Beacons.

On the other hand, using force charge solves both the 4 corners problem and the overlap problem.  Unfortunately it introduces one new problem: Beacons repelling each other.  I'm doing something like this to set up my charges:

```
force.charge(function(d){return d instanceof Beacon ? -1*(650 + nodes.length*20) : 0;})
```

This of course, results in Beacons that each have a negative charge.  Unfortunately, even though I set each Beacon's Fixed property to true, on force.start(), they still repel each other and fly across the graph.

Is there some way for me to tell D3 that it should only apply its repelling force to Regular Nodes?
Or do you have any suggestions for mimicking/patching D3's charge behavior to this effect?

Comment: You might be able to get what you want by creating a separate force layout for each beacon that contains all the regular nodes, but not beacons.